# Dropdown Not Showing Selected With Loaded Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

If I hardcode the data for a dropdown then I am able to get the dropdown selection showing using my code below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span id="make-selected">Make</span> <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="make-dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Oldsmobile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ford</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Volkswagen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Chrysler</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pontiac</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(){
    $('#make-selected').text($(this).text());
});
```

My issue is if I am loading my data from another source then it no longer shows the selection as shown below.

```
// the input for this is just a JSON file.
function populateDropdown(jsonData) {
    for (var m in jsonData) {
        $('#make-dropdown').append('<li><a href="#" data-maker="' + jsonData[m] + '">' + jsonData[m] + '</a></li>')
    }
}

$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(){
    $('#make-selected').text($(this).text());
    console.log("CLICKED" + this);
});
```

The dropdown list gets populated but once I click the selection nothing happens.

Comment: You need to use a delegated event handler as the content does not exist when the page loads. See the question I marked as duplicate for more information

Comment: thanks @RoryMcCrossan. I tried searching but I guess I didn't really know what exactly to search for. This solved it!

Comment: Your "this" is the wrong context. Try ``$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(e){
    $('#make-selected').text($(e.currentTarget).text());
});``